# R Shiny: Deleting objects in shiny environment

Tags: r, shiny

I've created an App that displays a datatable created from values of some input widgets.
I have implemented a feature that allows me to download the contents of the datatable as a CSV file by pressing a `downloadButton`.

I want to implement the option to reset/delete the contents of the datatable by the press of an `actionbutton`, in case I want to create a new datatable from scratch.

The contents of the datatable is stored as a dataframe object called `datatable`.

In a normal R session (when not running the app), I can easily delete/reset this object by manipulating the object in the global enviroment.

Both of these functions will accomplish what I need:

```
rm(datatable)
```

or

```
datatable <- datatable[0,]
```

However, I don't want to have to run this from the console everytime I want to reset the `datatable`.

I can't figure out how to apply this to the `actionbutton` in the Shiny app. I think it is because the `datatable` object is being stored in multiple code brackets (local enviroments) in the App and not stored in a global environment (correct me if I'm wrong here).

My approach was the following:

```
  observeEvent(input$delete_button, {
    rm(datatable)
  })
```

I would simply get the error message:

```
Warning in rm(datatable) : object 'datatable' not found
```

**My question is:** Is it possible to remove an object from a "Shiny global enviroment"? and if so, how should I go about implementing an actionbutton that can accomplish this?

Comment: 1) Create and treat your `datatable` as an *reactive*.  2) Set `datatable` to the same state as you initialize it on the first instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set

```
dtbl <- reactiveValue(datatable = NULL)

observeEvent(something, {
    dtbl$datatable <- fread(...)
})
```

you can then access it in the following manner

```
observeEvent(input$delete_button, {
    dtbl$datatable <- NULL  # puff and it's gone
})
```

Comment: I have one issue with the `reativeValues()` function.
The datatable is set to `NULL` each time I open the app.
I still want to be able to keep the values from the previous session when I open the app.
How can I define the `reactiveValues()` in order to keep the datatable?

My attempt:
`dtbl <- reactiveValues(if (exists("datatable")) {
  datatable = datatable
} else {
  datatable = NULL
})`
This did not work. Gave the error message: `Warning: Error in reactiveValues: All arguments passed to reactiveValues() must be named.`

Comment: I fixed the issue mentioned in previous comment by doing this:
```dtbl <- reactiveValues()
  
if (exists("datatable1")) {
  dtbl$datatable1 <- datatable1
} else { 
  dtbl$datatable1 <- NULL}```